# Javascript Password Verification window.location.replace

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication, passwords, verification

I have a site that I want to make a JavaScript login form.

Not like a perfect username & password login, But I want to build a password verification login. I want the user to redirect to private.html when they get it right, and to error.html when they get it wrong.

This is the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm() {
  x = document.getElementById("holy").value
  if (x == "mangos") {
    alert("Right Password!");
    window.location.replace("private.html");
  }
  else {
    alert("Wrong Password!");
    window.location.replace("home.html");
  }
}
</script>
<center>
<form class="form-container">
<center>
<div class="form-title"><h2>Login</h2></div>
<div class="form-title">Username</div>
<input class="form-field" type="text" name="username" /><br />
<div class="form-title">Password</div>
<input class="form-field" type="password" id="holy" name="password" /><br />
<div class="submit-container">
<button onclick="checkForm()" class="submit-button">Login</button>
</div> 
</center>
</form>
```

Apparently, the alert section in the function works, but then the next part of code, which is the window.location.replace doesn't work at all. Instead, the URL becomes

```
.com/password.html?username=asd&password=mangos
```

How should I do/fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the form is getting submitted, which is it's default behavior. To circumvent this, write a return false at the end of your checkForm() function.

```
function checkForm() {
  x = document.getElementById("holy").value
  if (x == "mangos") {
    alert("Right Password!");
    window.location.replace("private.html");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    alert("Wrong Password!");
    window.location.replace("home.html");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Though I had to add a return in the html part of the button. onclick="return checkForm()